# How can I access the prop of the objects in an array with function, for loop and a conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, object

I'd love to know how I can access the property of objects nested in an array through the use of function, for loop, and a conditional statement.

```
const details = [
  {
    first: "Liverpool",
    second: 'Man City',
    third: 'Chelsea',
    fourth: 'Tottenham',
    similarity: 'EPL'
  },
    {
    first: "Real Madrid",
    second: 'Barcelona',
    third: 'Villareal',
    fourth: 'Sevilla',
    similarity: 'La Liga'
  }
]



function team(name,prop){
  for (let i = 0; i < details.length; i++){
    if(details[i].first === name && details[i].name[prop] === prop){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

console.log(team('Liverpool','EPL'));
```

This isn't the main code but this should work. I'm trying to check if the second argument which is passed in the function call is a property of one of the objects. If it is one of it, it should return `true` if it isn't, it should return `false`.
To me, the main problem is on the 22nd line:
`....details[i].name[prop] === prop)`

I don't really know how to make that work. Please, help.

Comment: So you want to check if `EPL` is a _property_ of one of your objects? So the result should be `false`? Since the properties in your objects are `first`, `second`, `third`, `fourth` and `similarity` (EPL is a value, not a property)

Comment: Object.values (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) gives you all the values of an object.
Object.keys (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) gives you all the keys.

Comment: Yeah but not just EPL, if it's ```'Liverpool' and 'La Liga'```, it should return ```false```, if it's ```'Liverpool' and 'EPL'```, it should return ```true```. It should also be the same for the second object, too.

Comment: @c_froehlich Thanks, but the solution must have a function call, for loop and an if statement.

Comment: It wasn't meant as a solution but as a hint how to get all values / all keys from an object. You could work with it between the line with "for" and the line with "if" to get all values or keys. Your main problem is mixing keys and values in `details[i].name[prop] === prop`. It should read `details[i].name[key] === prop` and you could either get all keys from Object.keys(...) or you pass it into your function as a third param `team('Liverpool', 'similarity', 'EPL')`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the idea is to always compare with similarity, the method would be:

```
function team(name,prop){
  for (let i = 0; i < details.length; i++){
    if(details[i].first === name && details[i].similarity === prop){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
team('Liverpool', 'EPL')
```

But if the property can be dynamic it would be:

```
function team(name, prop, cup){
  for (let i = 0; i < details.length; i++){
    if(details[i].first === name && details[i][prop] === cup){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
team('Liverpool', 'similarity', 'EPL')
```

Another alternative is if you want to go through all the names, then it can be like this:

```
function team(name,prop){
  for (let i = 0; i < details.length; i++){
    const teams = Object.entries(details[i])
    const similarity = details[i].similarity;

    for (let j = 0; j < teams.length; j++){
      if (teams[j][1] === name && similarity === prop){
        return true;
      }
    }

  }
  return false;
}
team('Man City', 'EPL')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, these are very helpful. I'll try them out. The 1st and the 2nd seem really easy to comprehend than the third. Thanks very much.